# Questions on "The condition number of a randomly perturbed matrix"

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, matrix-analysis, random-matrices, additive-combinatorics, perturbation-theory

This question is about the two vectors $w'$ and $y$ that are necessary for the argument in section $7$ (page 6) of this paper by Terence Tao and Van Vu, 
https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0703307 (that section is titled as "Proof of Lemma 7.2" but I guess it is a typo and it should be Lemma 6.2)

Let me try to abstract out the confusing part here in as self-contained a way as I can.

For a set of $n-$dimensional random integral (polynomially bounded entries) vectors, $\{ X_1,..,X_n \}$ (these have special properties as specified in definition $2.15$ of the paper but I guess that its not relevant for this query) and constants $A >0$, $B >0$, let us define the following sets,

$\Omega = \{ w \in \mathbb{Z}^n: 0.9n^{B+2} \leq ||w|| \leq 1.1n^{B+2}\}$
$\Omega_1 = \{ w \in \Omega: \sup_{a \in \mathbb{Z}, 1 \leq i \leq n} \mathbb{P}[\langle X_i, w \rangle = a] \leq n^{-A-4}\}$

Let $M$ be a $n-$dimensional matrix such that $\exists w \in \Omega_1$ such that $\Vert M w \Vert \leq 2n^2$. (I guess one needs to imagine the random vectors $X_i$ defined above as rows of this matrix $M$ but then if the matrix is random then these arguments that follow get even more confusing to interprete!)

Now why is this enough to imply the following two things?

- that $\exists w' \in \Omega_1$ such that,
  $\Vert w' \Vert = \Vert w \Vert$ and $\Vert w' M\Vert \leq 2n^2$
- that $\exists y \in \Omega_1$ such that, it depends only on the first $n-1$ coordinates of $w$ (what the paper seems to refer as rows) such that, $\sqrt{ \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \langle X_i, y\rangle ^2} \leq 2n^2$ and $\Vert y \Vert \leq \frac{3}{2} \Vert w' \vert$

It would be very helpful if someone can help me understand these.